can subjective words be used in claims?
a method comprising:
identifying a group in part based on shared similar hobbies among its members.

The word "similar" is subjective.
Questions:

How will the examiner treat this?
In the event of litigation challenging the claim, if granted, how does the court treat this?


a method comprising:
identifying a group in part based on shared reasonably similar hobbies among its members

Does this modification matter, where the word "reasonably" is added?

Will readers of the claim be taught what you mean by similar hobbies by the specification?

yes, but the teachings do exhaust all possible "similar" hobbies. So ultimately, it still has room for subjective interpretation.

As written, your claim is not limited to computer implementation and covers mental processes as well, which renders it unpatentably abstract.
Assuming you limit to a computer-implemented method, such a claim will almost surely get means plus function treatment. Rather than being taken literally as any means for matching by similar hobby, it will be limited to those algorithms described in the specification. If the specification describes no algorithm for at least gauging the similarity of two hobbies (or similarity of lists of hobbies, which is more likely intended), the claim will be declared indefinite.

A specification can teach how to interpret such wording. It could explain  that indoor solitary hobbies are different from outdoor hobbies. Expensive hobbies are different than inexpensive ones. Some hobbies require artistic talent.
Claims often have wording like “an effective amount” and from the specs we see how to determine what is effective.
